# How to fix: Mail - Can't connect to the account "iCloud". Enter the password for user ""?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, smtp

Note that I am aware of this question: [Getting bizarre error message from Mail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281144/getting-bizarre-error-message-from-mail)

But, the single answer doesn't really provide enough info to fix the problem.

=====

This on an M1 MBA running 13.5.2

Suddenly I cannot send mail from this machine using an iCloud mail address. The mail fails with the message:

> Can't connect to the account "iCloud".  Enter the password for user
> "".

Connection Doctor says that the iCloud SMTP server is down with the following error:

```
READ Sep 22 15:15:03.104 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:smtp.mail.me.com -- port:587 -- socket:0x6000026953e0 -- thread:0x60000177fc40
501 5.7.0 Authentication aborted


WROTE Sep 22 15:15:03.105 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:smtp.mail.me.com -- port:587 -- socket:0x6000026953e0 -- thread:0x60000177fc40
QUIT
```

Connection Doctor on both my old Intel iMac and my wife's M1 iMac says that both the IMAP and SMTP iCloud servers are up.

I am able to send iCloud email using my iPhone, iPad the old iMac and the new iMac. It's only the new M1 MBA on which it fails.

Looks to me like Mail is either not sending the user name or password causing the "Authentication aborted" message.

But, I'm not sure how to fix this. The rest of iCloud (photos, drive, etc.) is working fine, so I'm doubtful that logging out of iCloud would help at all. It must be something else.

I did try restarting the machine, restarting Mail, turning iCloud mail off and on.

I contacted Apple Support and they closed the support chat with the following

> It seems to be an issue with the system at the moment Michael. I
> really apologize for the inconvenience.

But, that was two days ago and I still can't get the SMTP server to work, but only on the M1 MBA

Any ideas?